# Поворот 2d объекта - Python

Tags: python, разработка-игр, геометрия

Здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, каким образом правильно повернуть 2d объект? В данный момент есть код -

```
def rotate(self, teta, center=Point(0, 0)): # center - точка, вокруг которой происходит вращение
    ang = pi*teta/180

    self.x -= center.x
    self.y -= center.y

    self.x =  self.x*cos(ang)+self.y*sin(ang)
    self.y = -self.x*sin(ang)+self.y*cos(ang)

    self.x = self.x*cos(ang)-self.y*sin(ang)
    self.y = self.x*sin(ang)+self.y*cos(ang)  

    self.x += center.x
    self.y += center.y
```

При попытке его применить (см. код ниже), вращение не только происходит только в промежутке от 90 до -90 градусов, но и с изменением длинны линии.

```
point1 = (Vector(0,0)+self.player.pos)
point1.rotate(self.player.angle, self.player.pos)
point1 = point1.turp() #turp - метод вектора, возвращающий его в формате (x, y)

point2 = (Vector(20,0)+self.player.pos)
point2.rotate(self.player.angle, self.player.pos)
point2 = point2.turp()

self.canv.create_line(point1, point2, fill = 'red')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка скорее всего вот тут:

```
self.x =  self.x*cos(ang)+self.y*sin(ang)
self.y = -self.x*sin(ang)+self.y*cos(ang) // тут вы обращаетесь к уже измененному self.x
```

Нужно ввести промежуточные переменные:

```
x = self.x
y = self.y
self.x =  x*cos(ang)+y*sin(ang)
self.y = -x*sin(ang)+y*cos(ang)
```